# Oracle SQL - Modify the Content Based on the Value From Another

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I keep getting the ORA-00905: missing keyword error here. Could you take a look please?

The task is to replace the content of the attribute with 'N/A' if another variable is equal to 'R', otherwise - keep the value as is.

Here is an extract of my code:

```
SELECT
CASE 
   WHEN SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR1 = 'R' THEN SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR2 = 'N/A'
   ELSE SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR2
END AS NEW_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `select`, the column alias goes *after* the `select`.  `=` is not allowed in the `then` clause:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR1 = 'R' THEN 'N/A'
             ELSE SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR2
        END) AS NEW_NAME
```

Note:  You should use table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t.VAR1 = 'R' THEN 'N/A'
             ELSE t.VAR2
        END) AS NEW_NAME,
       . . .
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE t . ..
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an *update* here rather than a select, if you intend to change the data in your SQL table:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR2 = 'N/A'
WHERE SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR1 = 'R'
```

If you need to do a select here, then use the following:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR1 = 'R' THEN 'N/A' ELSE SCHEMA.TABLE.VAR2 END AS NEW_NAME
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the rights to update, so I need to conditionally extract the data.

Comment: @MaiiaS. Just make a slight change to your current query then in this case.